# Clearing text_field after ajax submit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am submitting a link with ajax. Everything works fine but when the form is reloaded I am unable to clear the text field.

Here is the form:

```
<%= simple_form_for [question, Link.new], :remote => true, html: {id: "new_link"} do |f| %>
 <%= f.input :description, as: :text, input_html: { :class => "createcomment" } %>
 <%= f.button :submit, "Post", class: "button" %>
<% end %>
```

This is what I have in create.js.erb (with all my attempts at the bottom):

```
$('.button').append("<%= j (render :partial => 'comments/newlink')  %>");
$('#linkpartial').html("<%= j (render :partial => 'comments/newlink')  %>"); 
$('#linkform').reset("<%= j (render :partial => 'links/form') %>");

# What I have tried...

$('.createcomment').val(''); 

$('#link_description').val('');     

$("#new_link").bind("ajax:complete", function(event,xhr,status){
   $('.createcomment').val('');
}    

$("#new_link").bind("ajax:complete", function(event,xhr,status){
   $('#link_description).val('');
}
```

I have also tried putting

```
$('#link_description').val('');
$('.createcomment').val('');
```

in a links_save.js.erb file.

The ajax:complete event handler prevents the partial and form from reloading and with .val(''); everything clears and reloads except it doesn't clear the description field.

Comment: Your first attempt should have worked. What are you doing with other js code in create.js.erb? Does it even fire? If it does then do you see any error in browsers console?

Comment: No need to replace the whole input just take the DOM id and clear the text filed, which you want to clear ?

Comment: Have you done a `console.log` to make sure that your completion handler is being run?

Comment: Not sure why but moving the last line up one made it work.

Answer (score 2):

Easy Fix.

In create.js.erb I had to move the last line above the second last like so:

```
$('.button').append("<%= j (render :partial => 'comments/newlink')  %>");
$('#linkpartial').html("<%= j (render :partial => 'comments/newlink')  %>"); 
$('.createcomment').val('');
$('#linkform').reset("<%= j (render :partial => 'links/form') %>");
```